# How to run code after an image has been loaded using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load an element only after the img element has been loaded, but I've tried everything I can think of and nothing is working. Right now I'm trying to see where the code stops working and I found that the alert I set up isn't running after the line I need the code to execute from.

```
$img = $('#picture');
function bubbleOnLoad() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $img.load(function(){
    alert('document loaded')
    $('#left-bubble').show();
  })
})
```

The $img is defined within a function. The alert works at the document.ready line but not after the `$img.load`. I have tried to add eventlisteners, jquery .on, .load, and a bunch of others. I'm also calling the function to run within my init function. Can someone explain to me why nothing is working?

```
function choosePic() 
 $('.speechbubble').hide();
 $('#picture').remove();
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * samplePics.length);
 var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function() {
  $('.playing-field').prepend(img);
 handleImageLoad();
 }
 img.src = samplePics[randomNum];
 img.id = "picture";
}


var samplePics = 
 "assets/images/barack-obama.jpg",
 "assets/images/donald-trump_3.jpg",
 "assets/images/dt-2.jpg",
 "assets/images/bill-clinton.jpg",
 "assets/images/Rose-Byrne.jpg",
 "assets/images/pic.jpeg", 
 "assets/images/priest.jpg", 
 "assets/images/tb.jpg",
 "assets/images/test.jpg", 
 "assets/images/amy-poehler.jpg",
 "assets/images/stephen-colbert.jpg",
 "assets/images/aziz-ansari.jpg"
];
```

Comment: is the img being loaded dynamically via JavaScript? Or with an img html tag?

Comment: Is the image cached in the browser?

Comment: did you read the docs, especially "Caveats of the load event when used with images" http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: why are you wrapping it in the bubbleOnLoad function?  is that function ever called?

Comment: Why is there a $(document).ready(function() inside of function bubbleOnLoad?  That seems very odd to me...

Comment: The braces are unbalanced, which probably isn't helping.

Comment: The braces within my code are correct, just maybe not on here. I have read and used every single doc known to man and nothing has worked. The image is being loaded dynamically with js, random image generator. The function is being called within the init function to get it to run. The document.ready within the function is the only thing that seems to be working. It may be strange, but I'm just trying to get to a working state at the moment.

Comment: @TiffanyHaltom can you post a more complete code. your current code is not giving any clue to us.

Comment: Not sure what else is needed, I can post where the images are coming from, but I don't think that would be terribly helpful?

Answer (score 4):

You had some syntax errors in your code which I corrected and came up with this:

```
function bubbleOnLoad() {
    $img = $('#picture');
    $img.load(function () {
        alert('document loaded');
        $('#left-bubble').show();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    bubbleOnLoad();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m7n1spr6/)

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem to work, I had the same exact code at one point. only at the end when I called it, I used the shorthand for document.ready- $(bubbleOnLoad);

Comment: @TiffanyHaltom Please do give me more details about what is not really working. Because when I tested the code, the `#left-bubble` is shown only after the picture has been loaded

Comment: I'm really not sure what's not working, it could be because of the event bubbling, I'd have to work with more. As the code you wrote stands, the image loads, but the bubble does not, but it does work with the JSFiddle you gave.

Comment: None at all, which makes me think it has something to do with the event bubbling. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In you code you are not even telling the browser it's supposed to run a code after image load. you should do something like this:

```
$(function(){

  // DOM Content is ready, let's interact with it.

  $('#picture').attr('src', 'image.jpg').load(function() {  
    // run code
    alert('Image Loaded');  
  });

});
```

Also [according to docs](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) a common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:

- It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
- It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
- It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
  Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Comment: I have this code for the image: ```function choosePic() {
 $('.speechbubble').hide();
 $('#picture').remove();
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * samplePics.length);
  var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function() {
   $('.playing-field').prepend(img);
   handleImageLoad();
 }
 img.src = samplePics[randomNum];
 img.id = "picture";
}```- and those are loaded with another function that is storing the images.

Answer (score 2):

Try this jQuery plugin **waitForImages**

https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

```js
//Javascript/jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
  var counter = 0,totalImages= $('#preloader').find('img').length; 
  $('#preloader').find('img').waitForImages(function() {
    //fires for all images waiting for the last one.
    if (++counter == totalImages) {
      $('#preloader').hide();
      yourCallBack();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/*css*/
#preloader{
  position:absolute;
  top:-100px;/*dont put in DOM*/
}

#preloader > img{
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML [add the plugin after jQuery] -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.waitforimages/1.5.0/jquery.waitforimages.min.js" ></script>
 

<!--HTML [after body start] -->
<div id=preloader>
  <img src="1.jpg" />
  <img src="2.jpg" />
  <img src="3.png" />
  <img src="4.gif" />
  <img src="5.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use the counter (in fact, currently it won't work), that function will be called only once *all* descendent images have loaded. Check the [docs](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the HTML element after it was created in DOM.
Also you need to check if the image was loaded before showing.
Thus your code need to look something as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    bubbleOnLoad(); 
});
      
function bubbleOnLoad() {
    var newSrc = "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-lFNPp0DRjgY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAD8/Fi3WUhXGOY0/photo.jpg?sz=328";
    $img = $('#picture');
    $img.attr('src', newSrc) //Set the source so it begins fetching
      .each(function() {
          if(this.complete) {
            alert('image loaded')
            $('#left-bubble').show();
          }
      });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left-bubble" style="display:none">
  <img id="picture"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please advise if my answer helps.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case since I'm only loading one image for the page until it refreshes, then I'm grabbing another, but thank you so much!